# Can't install Keras via Git on Centos

Tags: python, linux, tensorflow, keras, centos

I'm trying to find a way how to install Keras on Centos7 using Python and Git.

Git Clone Install

Here is the alternative install method for Keras using the GitHub source. (This assumes you have Git installed and working.) First, clone Keras using the following git command.

```
[root@host ~]# git clone https://github.com/keras-team/keras.git
```

Then, cd into the Keras folder and run the installation command.

```
[root@host ~]# cd keras
[root@host ~]# python setup.py install  <-- problem here
```

The problem is that there's no setup.py anymore, but the setup.cfg

How to install it then?

I don't have access to the server like a normal computer. I SSL to it through the command line and work just like that.

I tried just simple, but that's seems not the case

```
python setup.cfg install
```

But there are errors that don't make sense. I fix that and then appears another until I fixed almost all files but now the error almost makes no sense.

```
[root@cloudvpsserver keras]# python setup.cfg --update install
  File "setup.cfg", line 8
    per-file-ignores=*__init__.py:F401
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
[root@cloudvpsserver keras]# vim setup.cfg
[root@cloudvpsserver keras]# python setup.cfg --update install
  File "setup.cfg", line 8
    per-file-ignores=__init__.py:F401
                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
[root@cloudvpsserver keras]# vim setup.cfg
[root@cloudvpsserver keras]# python setup.cfg --update install[A
  File "setup.cfg", line 8
    per-file-ignores=__init__.py:
                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
[root@cloudvpsserver keras]# python setup.cfg --update install[A
  File "setup.cfg", line 8
    per-file-ignores=__init__.py:
                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
[root@cloudvpsserver keras]# vim setup.cfg
[root@cloudvpsserver keras]# python setup.cfg --update install[A
  File "setup.cfg", line 8
    per-file-ignores=__init__.py
SyntaxError: can't assign to operator
[root@cloudvpsserver keras]# python setup.cfg install
  File "setup.cfg", line 8
    per-file-ignores=__init__.py
SyntaxError: can't assign to operator
```

Comment: Your assumption that setup.cfg is used like a python script is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have installed and updated the correct packages for this?
also this looks like the file does not work well, because the line does not contain the correct indentation.
And I'm not sure if you need a requirements file to call it?
So if you are just getting the file from github check the .py file to verify everything is working well.

Comment: This is the official GitHub clone, so the file should work but they changed the extension, so probably if I find the right approach to how to install it that would be nice. There's no .py file I found something similar to that if I go into the folder the .py file that calls setup but it's not doing anything.

Comment: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/commit/b82ab804daf24d6091c449148a938083425155d3#diff-60f61ab7a8d1910d86d9fda2261620314edcae5894d5aaa236b821c7256badd7 here the last change of that file so If I download the old committed version there will be bunch of error with dependencies

Comment: Yes that can be you download the older version try with the new one.

Comment: i'm not sure about that. I downloaded the newest version from github itself. Still looking for an answer.